# How to merge maps by over writing null value in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

For example, I have two maps:

```
var map1 = {"a":"hello", "b":null};
var map2 = {"a":null, "b":"world"};
```

The result I want is:

```
{"a":"hello", "b":"world"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
map1.removeWhere((_, value) => value == null);
map2.removeWhere((_, value) => value == null);
final combinedMap = {...cleanMap1, ...cleanMap2};
```

Comment: This didn't work exactly. So i modified it little bit which worked. 
 ```map1.removeWhere((_, value) => value == null);
  map2.removeWhere((_, value) => value == null);
final combinedMap = {...map1, ...map2};```

Comment: You are right, removeWhere method modifies existing map, not returning a new one. I updated my answer now.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate through each (key, value) pairs in merged which is initialised to map1 and replace the value by the corresponding value in map2 if it's not null.

```
var map1 = {"a":"hello", "b":null};
var map2 = {"a":null, "b":"world"};
var merged = map1;

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(map2)) {
  if (value !== null){
    merged[key] = value;
}};

console.log(merged);
```

Comment: Just realised the question was in dart language but my answer is in javascript. You can easily convert that : )